# Writing with bold in Java using Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, bold

I'm writing a text editor in Java, using Swing. My main component that I use to enter the text is JTextPane. I know how to bold selected text, but I'd also like just to press bold and have new text formatted. Here's my code:

```
static void boldSelection(JTextPane editor, JButton button){
    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) editor.getDocument();
    int selectionEnd = editor.getSelectionEnd();
    int selectionStart = editor.getSelectionStart();
    if (selectionStart == selectionEnd) {
      return;
    }
    Element element = doc.getCharacterElement(selectionStart);
    AttributeSet as = element.getAttributes();

    MutableAttributeSet asNew = new SimpleAttributeSet(as.copyAttributes());
    StyleConstants.setBold(asNew, !StyleConstants.isBold(as));
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(selectionStart, editor.getSelectedText().length(), asNew, true);
}
```

It works, but I have no idea how to change it, since I have to pass the length to setCharacterAttributes.
To be clear:
that's what I have:
[Bolding selected text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNqWm.gif)
and that's what I want to do:
[Entering bolded text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr3qC.gif)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: you would be looking to have an action listener, which checked if you're in a "bold" state, and if so applies it to the entered character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EditorKit` used by the `JTextPane` supports a Bold `Action` along with other common actions the might be used by an editor. So you don't need to write any special code, only create a Swing component to use the `Action`.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for a working example.

The tutorial example only use menu items but you can also use the `Action` to create a `JButton` to add to a `JToolBar`.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks.